# Can I run win 10 on oVirt Host as desktop?

Tags: windows, ovirt

I am trying to understand if I can install win 10 VM on oVirt host/node and then use that PC as my win 10 desktop? running the win 10 VM?

Thanks.

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't seem to be very clear. If you are trying to check on running a windows 10 as a VM, then yes. You can have a look at this:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 0):

I later found that the host in itself can not be directly used and has to be accessed from other system.
So, no, win 10 VM running on the host can not be accessed from the same host.